# laravel mutator doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

Why my Laravel mutator does't work? I want to increment values in "like" column. Commented row works good, but mutator doesn't instead of commented one.

```
public function updateLike(Request $request){
    $comment = Comment::find($request->id);
    //$comment -> like = $comment-> like + 1;
    $comment -> save();
}

public function setLikeAttribute($value){
    return $this -> like = $value + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need use this in mutator

```
$this->attributes['like'] = $value + 1;
```

but for your case, mutator is not used for automatically increase a value,
you should use your commented code, not mutator.

Comment: Okay, I'll use commented row, but wanted understand why it doesn't work. I tried your sample also. It still doesn't work

Comment: the functionality of the sample code is actually whenever you save a value to `like`, it will automatically `+1`, so if you say `$comment->like = 2; $comment->save();`, you can see in database `like` is `3`

Comment: Yeah, I understood how it should work, but why my mutator-method does not work? I see value 2 in my database according to your last sample.

Comment: Of course. When I like comment in frontend I increment counter and write it to my DB. I use uncommented //$comment -> like = $comment-> like + 1; row for it. I see incremented value in phpmyadmin. But this value does not increment when I uncomment the mutator method ( I don't see any changes in phpmyadmin).

Comment: I tested the code, it's working, can you show me the code of the wrong test case? you can edit your question to paste the code.

Comment: yes it is working, but I used setLikeAttribute($value) method in controller instead of model. Thank you all guys!